# How to send a log to elastic search using FileBeat, with only one event?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat

I have several applications that generate logs in txt and log format and needed to send all the information to Kibana, I was able to send these logs but sending each line of the file in an event.
I would like to send all log lines in just one event, example of application log format:

```
16/09/2021 14:32:37 - [ INFO ] - Lendo arquivo de configuração
16/09/2021 14:32:38 - [ INFO ] - UID de Execução: d6649885-37f1-4f98-ba86-c23289fbad25
16/09/2021 14:32:41 - [ INFO ] - Iniciando extração de arquivo .RAR...
16/09/2021 14:32:42 - [ ERROR ] - Erro de execução: System.ArgumentException: File does not exist: C:\Users\07.903007\Desktop\Base 2\arquivo rar\BaseII_cbss_16092021.rar
   at SharpCompress.Archives.AbstractArchive`2..ctor(ArchiveType type, FileInfo fileInfo, ReaderOptions readerOptions)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.Rar.RarArchive..ctor(FileInfo fileInfo, ReaderOptions options)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.Rar.RarArchive.Open(String filePath, ReaderOptions options)
   at BaseII.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\07.903007\Desktop\teste\legacyautomation\BaseII\Program.cs:line 45
```

I would like to send all the log lines in just one event, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the `multiline` option in your `filbeat.yml` config under `filebeat.inputs` section.

Example config:

```yaml
multiline.type: pattern
multiline.pattern: '^\dd/dd/dddd'
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
```

That setup ensures that Filebeat takes all the lines that do not start with a date and combines them with the previous line that does.

The pattern is simply a regular expression.

If that's Java stack trace you can go even with this one, which is looking for a whitespace characters:

```yaml
multiline.type: pattern
multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]'
multiline.negate: false
multiline.match: after
```